# operator = on vectors of different dimensions

Tags: c++, operators, assignment-operator, assign

consider the following code:

```
class vector{
   // ...
   vector(int size){ /*...*/ };
   vector& operator= (const vector& other){
   // ...
   }
};

int main(){
   vector v1(5), v2(10);
   v1 = v2;
}
```

What is my `operator =` supposed to do here? `v1` does not have enough capacity to store the elements of `v2`. From my point of view, it can either reinitialize itself to a capacity of 10 and copy the other vector's elements or throw an exception. I usually choose the former approach but increasingly often see the latter one. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: Are you asking about what `std::vector` does? Or are you asking for advice on what you should do in your own vector class?

Comment: Do also note that a good implementation is to use the copy-swap idiom, which means your copy-constructor would also have to have this throwing behaviour and that would end terribly.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I am asking about a custom vector class! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically a user would expect that after an assignment `x = y`, the equality `x == y` should be true: assignment confers semantic equivalence. Doing anything else would be highly unusual and surprising. That probably includes not throwing an exception in response to the instruction "make `x` like `y`".

Comment: weird example. if it threw an exception, how could you expect that `x == y`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: You wouldn't expect to have to check an assignment for an exception, though.

Comment: That's why it's called an *exception* ;) e.g.: you could run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer I wanted to hear :D

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what a `vector` **is**.

If it's an automatic resizing vector, you would expect a resize. `std::vector` does just that.

If it's a mathematical vector for matrix operations, where you don't allow the vector size to change, then it should throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with mathematical vectors :)